# What is the first language to have inline commands in HTML code?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I'm learning PHP. The PHP has inline commands in HTML code to produce dynamic HTML output.

```
<div>
    <?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
</div>
```

In the Java and .NET world, there are similar syntaxes to have commands in HTML.

What is the first language or platform to have this kind of syntax, having dynamic code embedded in HTML code and generating dynamic HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First releases of

- [ADP](http://philip.greenspun.com/wtr/aolserver/introduction-1.html) 1994 (Greg Hewgill)
- [Server Side Includes](http://www.ordersomewherechaos.com/rosso/xssi/background/SSI.txt) 1994 (Thilo)
- [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/history.php.php) 1995
- [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) 1996
- [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) 1999

Comment: The first version of JSP was released in 1999.

Comment: If you’re collecting information from other answers, you should make your answer community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

[AOLserver](http://www.aolserver.com/) supported inline Tcl in that way back in 1994. For an example of how it looks, see the [Writing Your First ADP](http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/Writing_Your_First_ADP) tutorial. Also, Phil Greenspun has an excellent [Introduction to AOLserver](http://philip.greenspun.com/wtr/aolserver/introduction-1.html) written in 1999.

Comment: PHP is born in 1994. Which is earlier?

Comment: @Morgan: According to the official history it is 1995 ... see my post for the link.

Answer (score 1):

The first I have come across have been [Server-Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). They have been introduced in the [NCSA web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCSA_HTTPd) version 1.2, in 1994.

Before that, they had a simpler system using `INC SRV` tags, like `<inc srv "|date">` to include the current date. The oldest reference to that I could find was [a question on a mailing list](http://1997.webhistory.org/www.lists/www-talk.1993q4/0411.html), dating back to November 1993.